# How can I include LookBehind expression in the match?

Tags: c#, regex

`(?<=expression)` lets me assert that the text before the "match" matches the expression. Is there a way of getting performance benefits from LookBehind, but still keeping the expression within the match?

Comment: If you need the expression in the match, you don't need lookbehinds

Comment: Then maybe I'm misunderstanding how the engine works. (?<=\w+)@[0-9]+ performs the same as \w+@[0-9]+? In my specific scenario I have a complex expression instead of \w, but I don't need the engine to waste time trying to match it if there's not even a @ in the string.

Comment: Have you tried doing it without lookbehind and including the expression in the match, as @RodrigoLópez points out?  I.e. if you haven't tried it how do you know that it won't work from a performance perspective?  If you've tried it, what happened?

Comment: That's what is currently in production. It performs very poorly. With LookBehind it performs much faster, but I need to replace the whole expression, including the LookBehind.

Comment: Try making the `@` you look behind or ahead for, since that is a known and constant thing.  Something like (expression)(?!@)[0-9]+.  This way maybe you preserve benefit of lookahead/behind, but you can capture expression.  BTW, what are you trying to capture? expression, I get, but are you also trying to capture [0-9]+?

Comment: @Miguel Did you found a solution to this?